# How can I check if mouse button is left or right in wpf C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, mouse

I'm trying this code actually I have created only one Eventhandler that is on `Click="button_Click"`.

XAML:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WPFAPP.Window1" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFAPP"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window1" Height="447.625" Width="562">

    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="btn1" Content="Button1" Click="button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn2" Content="Button2" Click="button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn3" Content="Button3" Click="button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn4" Content="Button4" Click="button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,137,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn5" Content="Button5" Click="button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,174,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind C#:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    if(e.Equals(Mouse.RightButton))
    {
        button.ClearValue(Button.BackgroundProperty);
        button.Background = Brushes.Green;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I thought button click always had to be your main button (right or left depending on your pc setup) ..

Comment: Actually sir my problem is on if statement because if i remove (if statement )then my code work fine but then it doesn't check about mouse click

Comment: I am NOT male ... then what values do you get in e (which was originally going to be my question) because I very sure e is not just mousebutton

Comment: `if(e.Equals(Mouse.RightButton))` will always be false. `e` is an instance of `RoutedEventArgs` and can never be `Mouse.RightButton`. If you want to allow both / do different things on Left/Right, use the MouseDown event instead. If you only want to handle left clicks, remove the if entirely.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? I smell an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: yes sir #Manfred you are right if i remove the (if statement) then left button will work fine but my problem is to know first the pressed Mouse button is left or right?

Comment: @BugFinder doesn't have to be just left mouse, doesn't even have to be mouse which is the problem

Comment: Sir #Abion I just want to know which mouse side is clicked left or right.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer answer my question for you, its RoutedEventArgs (which I knew) you have ignored his answer. You are going about it the wrong way

Comment: @Shahbaz You'll find your answer below (by @MikeT). From what I can tell by your comments you'll need the `MouseDown` event. In the event handler you can check `e.ChangedButton == Mouse.RightButton`.

Comment: @Shahbaz Reply to people using the `@` character, not the `#` character. Otherwise, we won't get the notification, and your reply could very easily go unnoticed.

Comment: @Abion47 thanks sir I tried your code e.ChangedButton == Mouse.RightButton but it giving me an error (RoutedEventArgs does not contain any defination)

Comment: Sounds like you are still trying to use the `Click` event instead of the `MouseDown` or `MouseUp` events. Also, it wasn't my code. Make sure you also reply to the correct person.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer sir I tried your code e.ChangedButton == Mouse.RightButton but it giving me an error (RoutedEventArgs does not contain any defination)

Comment: @MikeT Sir I tried your code MouseUp and Down and double click also but it giving me an error (The event.UIElement.MouseDown can only appear on the left hand side+= or-=)

Comment: @Shahbaz It will work with MouseDown. MouseDown uses MouseEventArgs, not RoutedEventArgs.

Comment: @Shahbaz You have no idea what you are doing, do you?

Comment: Recommended Reading: [Events in WPF](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/xaml/events-in-xaml/), [Getting started with C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664628(v=vs.71).aspx), [Asking questions on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer sir this is a litttle logic of an a project I could not post whole scenario that's why i post a simple example.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Thanks your code is correct i tried and thanks of all you peoples!

Comment: @Shahbaz Great to hear that, I'm sure MikeT would appreciate it if you would click the checkmark next to his answer (this also signals other users that this question has already been answered)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Click is only designed for the most limited interaction, if you use the more advanced mouse events you then get a MouseButtonEventArgs which gives you all details about the event.

the reason for this is that Click isn't a mouse event, you could also trigger it with a touch, stylus, you can even trigger it with the keyboard by pressing Return while highlighted

so try MouseDown, MouseUp or DoubleClick instead

eg

```xml
<Button MouseDoubleClick="Button_MouseDoubleClick" >Click me</Button>
```

```cs
private void Button_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Right)
    {
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

or for mouse down

```xml
<Button MouseDown="Button_MouseDown" >Click me</Button>
```

```cs
private void Button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Right)
    {
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: That error is from trying to trigger event outside of the event's owner

Comment: @Shahbaz i've put how to call the event into the example

Comment: There are two separate events for left and right button MouseLeftbuttondown and MouseRightbuttondown.

Comment: @Rudra that there are though i never personally bother with them the simple `ChangedButton` check is quick to write and easier to change than changing the event wireup if you change your mind about how something should interact at a future date, not to mention if i car about if its left or right thats usually because i want something to happen on both

Comment: @MikeT thanks of you now my problem is solved and your code is correct and working fine!

Comment: We can have small function unit, which can be called from the multiple events that will increase the maintainability. Other wise we can implement the mouse down event  at grid level for all  buttons and don't need to define event at button level.

Answer (score 1):

It's always better to have separate event handler for left and right mouse down. If you need to work as per the clicked button. Below is my approach.

```xml
<Button MouseLeftButtonDown="Button_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseRightButtonDown="Button_MouseRightButtonDown"></Button>
```

Below is code behind.

```cs
private void Button_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

}

private void Button_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

}
```

If you want to get the button which cause the event, you can check the `e.OriginalSource` property.

Comment: I would disagree about the always better part as its always better to do things once instead of several times, it is possible that you you want different belabour for left, right Middle, Special1, special2 or any multiple button combination a simple MouseDown will handle all of these where has left and right wont

Comment: So, Are going to support Grid level MouseDown Event handling for all buttons?

Comment: Depends if that is required, generally you just want to activate the button so the method of activation is irrelevant in which case i would just Bind a command, but if i do need to have multiple ways of activating the same control then i always aim for a single point of entry

Comment: just to be clear though i'm not saying that using the right and left events is wrong i'm just saying that your statement that they are "always better" is over broad, there are many situations where they are actively worse such as when you need to consider multiple buttons pressed at once, like everything in coding better depends on situation

Comment: Yes, If that is the case then the single entry point is better option other wise it's good to have separate event which will be less error prone.

Comment: @MikeT sir now I want to do with single click so which properties of a Button will be used As you know and you told me yesterday "MouseDoubleClick" that is working fine for me for Doubleclick One more thing I have tried MouseDown properties which is not working

Comment: @Shahbaz It will work with any Mouse button event see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx I would suggest MouseUp or MouseDown, Rudra MouseRightUp or MouseRightDown

Comment: I will go with click event that will fire on mouse click and keyboard enter both. If you need to check which button has down of mouse the MouseUp and MouseDown. :)

Answer (score 0):

By using MVVM you can do for *Left button Double Click on a ListView Item* for example :

The Namespace to add in "Window" or "UserControl"

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

The ListView :

```
<ListView x:Name="lvComputers"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          ...>
  <!-- Double Click -->
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ListViewComputers_MouseDoubleClick}"
                               CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=lvComputers, Path=SelectedItem}"
                               />
     </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListView>
```

and then the binded event :

```
private void ListViewComputers_MouseDoubleClick(object obj)
{
   //Allow only left button double click
   if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
   {
      //Code to execute on Left Button Double Click
   }
}
```

"Mouse" needs :

```
using System.Windows.Input;
```